# What could be breaking Keynote Live?

Tags: icloud, keynote

Keynote Live seems like a very useful feature.  I thought I would try it out using Keynote.app in advance of a presentation in January.

[image: Share menu, Use Keynote Live...]

No matter what I do, it always tells me to wait for the Keynote to upload:

[image: keynote dialog telling you to wait]

However I know beyond a shadow of a doubt that this dialog box is false. I shared the presentation through iCloud with other people and they were able to download it.  This proves it is ON iCloud. What could be going wrong?

Comment: Are you using the one on iCloud or local?

Comment: The real local app, not the browser app.